# How to disable proxy for flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app on the android studio, Proxy is disabled from the android studio as well IE, and using open network but still getting a proxy error, Is there any separate proxy config. for flutter, If, How to remove it?
It works fine for other Android projects, only for flutter app this issue comes

Comment: What error message do you get exactly?

Comment: @babeena kurian im having the same problem im running it from the command line on Mac and receiving proxy authentication error, but I already defined the proxy with export but still isn't working, probabilly there is another config file exclusive for flutter. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

for me ,
on windows ,
i have deleted the properties with `systemProp.http` in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is not exactly on flutter, but on git wich is used to push/pull files..
Try clean the proxy on git:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy

git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

or take a look in the git configuration file `~/.gitconfig` and delete manually the proxy configuration.